# Can't create app from Facebook business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-apps

I have created a business page for the new company I am working for (completely separate from my personal account). I have discovered that with a business page, you cannot create apps or tabs or anything involving the developer app!

I know you can create an app from your personal account and link it to your business page, but does the business page have to have been created through your personal account?

Can you link an app made from your personal profile, to a completely separate business page that you have made?

Answer (score 0):

The page that you want to add your app to does not have to be created by the same person as the app itself. After creating the app with URL for tab pages configured all you have to do is providing a person with admin role on the page with following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=URL_OWNED_BY_YOUR_FB_APP
```

After that the person who entered this URL will be able to choose the page that she or he wants to create a tab with this app for. Of course only pages that the person has admin role will be visible. So even if the bussiness page would be created and administered by someone else than you, there is no problem with including your app in the page.